# Google Analytics stats erroneously dropped 97%

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Ok, so my website has had a random event. The ga that I had installed was report 100 visitors a day. Now it is reporting 3. Webmaster tools is still showing 100. I checked the code and it is retrieving data (obviously since it reports 3, but clearly not all). I ran ga debugger. I got 3 warnings and 2 errors. There is only one instance of ga, running in the footer. The problem is, I don't know what to do to correct these errors. Any feedback is welcome. Thanks

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("create", "", "auto")
analytics_debug.js:10 Creating new tracker: t0
analytics_debug.js:10 Auto cookieDomain found: "mysite.com"
analytics_debug.js:10 The tracking Id should only be of the format UA-NNNNNN-N.         **(WARNING)**
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Tracking ID not set. Aborting hit.                                **(ERROR)**  
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXXX-X", "auto")
analytics_debug.js:10 Ignoring create request for duplicate tracking name.              **(WARNING)**
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Tracking ID not set. Aborting hit.                                **(ERROR)**  
analytics_debug.js:10 Initializing Google Analytics. 
Tracking script already loaded. Abandoning initialization.                              **(WARNING)**
follow_button.37e112509e16b7fe5e4cf93632594a08.en.html:1 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi)
```

Here is the code, taken straight from ga and inserted into my site:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Show us the tracking code itself. The error is saying that your Tracking ID is not set.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the code. Thanks for looking at it Pete TNT

Comment: Are you sure you are not including the tracking code twice? Everything else seems to be correct

Comment: I went through everything. I checked the source code and found one instance of ga. 

To be safe, I manually reviewed all plugins and the header, footer, and any other file related to them. There is only one instance of ga.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Another object on my site is using the ga aspect of the analytics script. So, I rewrote ga to be _gaTracker. There are 3 changes to make:

```
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

becomes

```
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','_gaTracker');
```

and

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

become

```
_gaTracker('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
_gaTracker('send', 'pageview');
```

That is all it takes.